# How do you return back to the HomeView after hitting a complete/submitted button?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-environment

I am running into an issue now. When I click on the button in my ResultsView, it does not go back to ContentView. It was previously working, and now is not for some reason. I have to use the navigation’s back button to go back to the ContentView. Another issue I am having is that the ResultsView will pop up and display quickly before the questions are being displayed. Does the version of Xcode matter in this case?

Here is my ResultsView

```
struct ResultsView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentViewModel
    
    var numberCorrect: Int
    
    
    var resultsText: String {
        if numberCorrect >= 8 {
            return "Awesome Job!"
        } else if numberCorrect >= 6 {
            return "Not bad. I think you can do better!"
        } else {
            return "You should study more"
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.primaryColor
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack (spacing: 30) {
               
                Text("\(numberCorrect) out of \(model.currentQuiz?.course.test.questions.count ?? 0)")
                    .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .heavy))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            
                Text(resultsText)
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
               
                Button {
                    model.currentCourseTestSelected = nil
                  
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .fill(.white)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                        Text("Complete")
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
               
                

            }
            
        }
        
      
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
       
            ZStack {
                Color.primaryColor
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Select a Quiz of Your Choice!")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.leading, 20)
                        .padding(.top, 40)
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVStack{
                        ForEach(model.quizModules) {
                            quiz in
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: QuizView()
                                .onAppear(perform: {
                                    model.getFirebaseQuestions(module: quiz) {
                                        model.beginQuizModule(quiz.course.test.id)
                                    }
                                  
                                }),
                                           tag: quiz.course.test.id.hash,
                                           selection: $model.currentCourseTestSelected)
                            {
                                CourseCard(category: quiz.category, description: quiz.course.description, image: quiz.course.image)
                            }
                           
                            
                        
                        }//ForEach Loop
                        }//LazyVStack
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
            }//ScrollView
        //NavigationView
    }
}
```

Comment: What button? Are you talking about the default back button, or something else?

Comment: I have a Button in the ResultsView that when press should return to ContentView but isn't. Based on suggestion from Brado below, it may have to deal with my NavigationView. I have a WelcomeView that contains a button moves into ContentView. That has the NavigationView which may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As see from comments in ContentView, you had NavigationView(). Now there's no NavigationView there.
Also you have `.navigationBarHidden(true)` and it hide back button in child view. I think your issue is here.
Second question is needed to be explained more detail.

Comment: Oh okay. I have a WelcomeView that contains a button moves into ContentView. That has the NavigationView which may be the issue.